# If $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \ x_{n} =-\infty$ then why $\lim_{n\to\infty} \ x_{n} =-\infty$?

Tags: limits, limsup-and-liminf

I cannot understand why, if $\limsup_{n\to\infty} \ x_{n} =-\infty$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \ x_{n} =-\infty$? Can anybody explain it? What's the relationship between $\limsup$ and $\lim$?

Comment: Basically $\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} =- \infty$ means that there is a subsequence $\{ x_n \}_{n \geq k }$ with supremum smaller than any $M \in \mathbb{Z}$. Therefore every $x_n$ must become arbitrarily small.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following relation holds: $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} x_n \leq \limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n$$
If $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ exists (in $\mathbb{R}\cup \{-\infty,\infty\})$ and are equal, we define $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} x_n = \liminf_{n \to \infty} x_n = \limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n$$
Therefore, if $\limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n = - \infty$ we must have $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = -\infty$.

Comment: Could you please help with this question related to if: If $\lim_{x \to \infty} x_n = \liminf_{n \to \infty} x_n = \limsup_{n \to \infty} x_n= -\infty$ then there's no convergent subsequence  of $x_n$? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By definition, 
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty} x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup\{x_n,x_{n+1},\ldots\},
$$
and
$$
x_n\leq\sup\{x_n,x_{n+1},\ldots\}.
$$

Comment: If $x_n\leq\sup\{x_n,x_{n+1},\ldots\}$ then $\lim x_n\leq\lim \sup\{x_n,x_{n+1},\ldots\}$?